# Vaadin - grid.getDataProvider().refreshAll(); Does not work after updating browser

Tags: grid, vaadin

how are you ? I have a detail with the push after updating the tab that contains my grid, I am using vaadin 8.0.4 
,google chrome updated, and my example is based here https://github.com/vaadin/archetype-application-example

My application consists of data stored in mongodb, when I make a direct change in the db it is reflected in the grid every so often, 30 seconds, with push, it always works on a single tab, the problem appears when I update the tab or create a new one, the push seems to be disconnected and my grid is not updated anymore, the strange thing is that I added the @PreserveOnRefresh and in the first tab that accesses the application in that if the push works even after updating very strange.

This instance check changes in my db

```
private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
```

and

I use the grid update, with

```
grid.getDataProvider().refreshAll()
```

I even try to broadcast the tabs, by means of the pattern described in the book 12.16.4. Broadcasting to Other Users
because if the active notifications continue in all the tabs, **but the grid does not, only in the original tab.**

---

Update:
In this example application the problem is actually the login, when I remove it if everything works perfectly as it should be with push. But only when I remove **the login**

```
@Override
public void receiveBroadcast() {
   access(() -> {
    //Notification.show(message);
    //grid.getDataProvider().refreshAll();
    getNavigator().removeView(MonitorCrudView.VIEW_NAME);
    getNavigator().addView(MonitorCrudView.VIEW_NAME,new MonitorCrudView(this));
    getNavigator().navigateTo(MonitorCrudView.VIEW_NAME);
    Notification.show("Grid updated", Notification.Type.TRAY_NOTIFICATION);
   });
}
```

The detail is that when I have the AccessContro enabled, and I enter as admin by what you see, when executing the above method I get an exception of type **"No request linked to the current thread"**; Coming from the "CurrentUser" Class
https://github.com/vaadin/archetype-application-example/blob/master/mockapp-ui/src/main/java/org/vaadin/mockapp/samples/authentication/CurrentUser.java

***But here in vaadin 8.0.4 changes a little***

```
public final class CurrentUser {

    /**
     * The attribute key used to store the username in the session.
     */
    public static final String CURRENT_USER_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_KEY = CurrentUser.class
            .getCanonicalName();

    private CurrentUser() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the current user stored in the current session, or an
     * empty string if no user name is stored.
     * 
     * @throws IllegalStateException
     *             if the current session cannot be accessed.
     */
    public static String get() {
        String currentUser = (String) getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession()
                .getAttribute(CURRENT_USER_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_KEY);
        if (currentUser == null) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return currentUser;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the name of the current user and stores it in the current session.
     * Using a {@code null} username will remove the username from the session.
     * 
     * @throws IllegalStateException
     *             if the current session cannot be accessed.
     */
    public static void set(String currentUser) {
        if (currentUser == null) {
            getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession().removeAttribute(
                    CURRENT_USER_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_KEY);
        } else {
            getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession().setAttribute(
                    CURRENT_USER_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_KEY, currentUser);
        }
    }

    private static VaadinRequest getCurrentRequest() {
        VaadinRequest request = VaadinService.getCurrentRequest();
        if (request == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "No request bound to current thread");
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

[Https://github.com/rucko24/testView/blob/master/MyApp-ui/src/main/java/example/samples/crud/SampleCrudView.java](https://github.com/rucko24/testView/blob/master/MyApp-ui/src/main/java/example/samples/crud/SampleCrudView.java)

In this class I added the button that broadcast to all UI.

- Log in as admin
- Click on Update grid
- Should give a type exception

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No request bound to current thread

- Does not continue to throw exeption after refreshing the UI
  But when opening in an incognito tab it always throws the exception once before updating.
- With the base project and mongo db plus the

> private static ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
>   Executors.newScheduledThreadPool (5);

I always get the same exception from above, and never change the view with push

Comment: Any chance you could share a [sscce](http://sscce.org) on github or similar (forget the DB just use some static data), and a list of steps to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Thanks a lot I appreciate it very much, I'm trying to reproduce the error without mongodb, in the application itself example 8.0.4 but I still do not achieve it. @Morfic

Comment: Hello @Morfic you are in some way hahahaha, I do not know if it is too much to ask but could you see the code in example github?

Comment: I checked your code, please see bellow a possible response. _Off-topic_: I'm currently travelling so I may not be able to quickly reply to your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** This is better suited as a comment but it does not fit the allocated space.

---

The [`VaadinService.getCurrentRequest()` API doc](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.5/com/vaadin/server/VaadinService.html#getCurrentRequest--) states that:

> The current response can not be used in e.g. background threads because of the way server implementations reuse response instances.

At the same time, the [`UI.access()` javadoc](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.5/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#access-java.lang.Runnable-) is somewhat ambiguous stating that:

> Please note that the runnable might be invoked on a different thread or later on the current thread, which means that custom thread locals might not have the expected values when the command is executed

The above statements kind of explain why `VaadinService.getCurrentRequest()` is null in your `getCurrentRequest()` method.

Nonetheless, it seems that UI.getCurrent() returns an instance when running in that background thread, also suggested by [this vaadin forum post](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/9643057) and vaadin book:

> Your code is not thread safe as it does not lock the VaadinSession before accessing the UI. The preferred pattern is using the UI.access and VaadinSession.access methods as described in [Book of Vaadin section 11.16.3.](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html#advanced.push.running) Inside an access block Vaadin automatically sets the relevant threadlocals in addition to properly handling session locking.

In conclusion, i'd suggest to replace all the calls to `getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession()` with `UI.getCurrent().getSession()`;, eg:

```
UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute(CURRENT_USER_SESSI‌​ON_ATTRIBUTE_KEY);
```

or

```
UI.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute(CURRENT_USER_SESSI‌​ON_ATTRIBUTE_KEY, currentUser);
```

I tested this with your sample and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help I thank you, with the browser change if it works perfectly and with my ScheduledExecutorService, which does the update for me without the button, now the grid.getDataProvider (). RefreshAll (); Does not refresh all the UI, but really that with the first works